# Installing VNC on openSUSE

Tags: linux, command-line, opensuse, vncserver

Anyone have any idea on how to install VNC through cli, cant find any instructions on it on opensuse. I'm new to the whole thing and I can only ssh into my machine.

I find CLI to be very difficult and I would like to be able to make changes through GUI, I passed my gpu to a vm. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server (vncserver) can be installed running as root:

```
zypper install xorg-x11-Xvnc
```

The client (vncviewer):

```
zypper install xorg-x11-Xvnc
```